# No module found error while deploying Django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I've installed the `django-admin-bootstrapped` module in my django application. When I run `cat requirements.txt` it shows:

```
django-admin-bootstrapped==1.6.4
```

However, when I run the application using `python manage.py runserver 8000` using virtualenv, it gives me the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named django_admin_bootstrapped
```

What I find funny is that this error arises when I run the application from the terminal. However, if I run this app from my IDE (PyCharm), it runs perfectly. Am I missing out on anything?

EDITS:

OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Python: v2.7
Steps to install module: 
I used the instructions from [this website](https://riccardo.forina.me/bootstrap-your-django-admin-in-3-minutes/)

If there's any more logs or code that is needed, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: please show output of: pip freeze | grep bootstrap

Comment: If you are using virtualenv, is the environment activated in terminal? Is `django-admin-bootstrapped` added in your settings `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @zymud, the terminal gave no output with that command.

Comment: @zymud, i tried it with the virtualenv, off. It gave me this result: django-admin-bootstrapped==1.6.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course django-admin-bootstrapped IS added in INSTALLED_APPS, otherwise runserver wouldn't complain about the missing module. Please, try what @zymud said and post pip freeze | grep bootstrap output. Anyway, if the module works in pyCharm, i think you have a PATH issue...

Make sure that the directory containing the django-admin-bootstrapped module is in your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Ps. When dealing with installation issues, it would be great to know something about the system (OS, Python version, steps you made to install the module).

EDIT:

I just noticed you are using virtualenv... did you activate the virtualenv (workon VIRTUAL_ENV_name) before installing django-admin-bootstrapped with pip?

Comment: Yes, my virtualenv (venv) was active when I installed the module.

Comment: that's strange... I see in the comments above that if you do the pip freeze command with virtualenv off everything is ok... Are you sure that pyCharm is working on the same virtualenv you activated in terminal? From what you get from pip freeze i would say that you installed the module in your system environment, not in virtual one...

Comment: Okay, so I did a `which django-admin.py` inside the PyCharm console and it seems to give me a system environment path. Changing this to the local venv path might help. I'll test and get back to you.

Comment: Changing perspective, you could add the folder containing django-admin-bootstrapped to the virtualenv (if you're using virtualenvwrapper, you can do the command 'add2virtualenv directory'. This could be great also if you want to share some modules between different virtualenvs...

Comment: Hey, that does help a lot. I added the folder to venv and it's working perfectly now. Thanks a lot. Sorry for not providing thorough info earlier. Thanks again!

Comment: Very glad to be helpful! If this solved for you, you could vote/accept this answer ;-) Going back on topic: Virtualenv are very useful for separating different python environments where you want to install conflicting apps (example: you have env1 containing a project using django 1.4, but for a new project you need django 1.6, which would break the previous code, so you create a new env2 in which you install 1.6 without touching env1). The addition of a path folder to virtualenv is useful for sharing non-conflicting modules. By this you can avoid installing common modules in every single v.env

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your module names are the same both in your sitepackage folder and your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

It seems that your module name is "django-admin-bootstrapped" but you set the
INSTALLED_APPS like this:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django_admin_bootstrapped',
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bootstrap_admin/0.3.0

Install
NOTE: I’m assuming you use pip to install the Python Packages.
from latest version on pypi

```
$ pip install bootstrap-admin
```

from github master branch

$ `pip install git+https://github.com/douglasmiranda/django-admin-bootstrap`
or clone the master branch in your machine

$ `git clone https://github.com/douglasmiranda/django-admin-bootstrap`
And don’t forget to add bootstrap_admin in INSTALLED_APPS before the django.contrib.admin.